# how to redirect page in different project in same solution in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have one solution called : MainProject : - have 6 project in solution,

i want to link 5 project starting page from 6th project aspx , how could  i do that?

```
from 6th project(as solution starting project) , default.aspx page 

Link1 : open 1st project starting page
Link2 : open 2st project starting page
Link3 : open 3rd project starting page
Link4 : open 4th project starting page
Link5 : open 5th project starting page
```

More explanation : i have lots of small projects in asp.net , i put them in one solution, now from one default.aspx page , i need to see all project starting page

Comment: Set the 6th as the start project?

Comment: @Grixxly yes, 6th as start project

Comment: Then right click the 6th project and select it to be startup project

Comment: @Grixxly, assume that it's already set in solution .. what's next to redirect :P

Comment: What do you mean by redirect? You've provided very little information

Comment: @Grixxly , thx for reply , look, i have Solution Called X,  x have 2 project called A ,and B, from project A page, there is one button, if i clicked there, i want to see project B's page !

Comment: Are you trying to use MVC framework or? What you want is not clear at all. I would edit your question.

Comment: @Grixxly, if you're using DevExpress, they have demo project, where one solution contains lots of project for each control, they are open ing those page starting page from one page,

Comment: So this is a tutorial? I'm using pro so maybe you can link the tutorial if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

- Each of your projects is its own web site or web application
- When you publish any/all of them, they will be different web sites/applications
- you can link and/or redirect to any of their pages just like you would between different web sites

If you are asking how to simply run all of your projects **while you are developing** then you can right click on any page from each project and "view in browser". Note the port that visual studio assigns (`http://localhost:**12345**) to each page -this is how Visual Studio simulates different web sites.

You can also move all of them to IIS, assign each its own IP and do it that way.

The point is that they are distinct web sites/applications (I don't want to confuse you, but this isn't a hard rule - one of your projects can also be a sub *application* within some other).